# How To create RestClient with Spring Boot Application in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, spring-tool-suite

I am new to STS. I am creating RESTful Web Services with the Jersey implementation using the Gradle Build tool. Can any one tell me how to create or consume REST in STS?

Comment: STS is the IDE for Spring. Are you wanting something like postman in Eclipse? Or are you trying to make a Java app that can call Restful endpoints? If that is the case then spring offers the RestTemplate class to do that

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot provides many sample projects on GitHub that can be used for getting started on a new project. In your case the [Jersey sample project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-rest) should provide you with a good starting point.

After download the sample source code you can import the project into STS using `File -> Import` and select `Existing Maven Project`.